# How use hegel.js with React app(create-react-app)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, babeljs, create-react-app

Hegel.js is an advanced type checker. I found nothing in internet about using hegel.js with React. https://hegel.js.org/

Comment: Can you be more specific? What do you asking exactly (and please add some code)

Comment: I just want to configure hegel.js with React app. For code you can use simple React app (create-react-app).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible at the moment. [Hegel doesn't work with JSX](https://github.com/JSMonk/hegel/issues/37)